# How to submit pyspark jobs in Apache livy?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, amazon-emr

```
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1 --jars /usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC4.jar /home/hadoop/test.py
```

How to specify the above (pyspark ) spark-submit command in Apache livy format?

I tried the following:

```
    curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/home/hadoop/test.py", "conf": 
    {"com.databricks": "spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1"}, \
    "queue": "my_queue", "name": "Livy  Example",  "jars" : 
    "/usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC4.jar"}', \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches
```

[Refered the following livy article spark livy rest api](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/151164/how-to-submit-spark-application-through-livy-rest.html)

Also getting the following error:

```
"Unexpected character ('“' (code 8220 / 0x201c)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 37]
```

Comment: Did you cut & paste wrong or are those smart quotes in your data?  (See around `conf` and `com.databricks` ...)

Comment: Let me check that...

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is  wrong , Please use following example to construct command .

**spark-submit command**

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \

--jars a.jar,b.jar \

--pyFiles a.py,b.py \

--files foo.txt,bar.txt \

--archives foo.zip,bar.tar \

--master yarn \

--deploy-mode cluster \

--driver-memory 10G \

--driver-cores 1 \

--executor-memory 20G \

--executor-cores 3 \

--num-executors 50 \

--queue default \

--name test \

--proxy-user foo \

--conf spark.jars.packages=xxx \

/path/to/examples.jar \

1000
```

**Livy REST JSON protocol**

```
{
“className”: “org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi”,

“jars”: [“a.jar”, “b.jar”],

“pyFiles”: [“a.py”, “b.py”],

“files”: [“foo.txt”, “bar.txt”],

“archives”: [“foo.zip”, “bar.tar”],


“driverMemory”: “10G”,

“driverCores”: 1,

“executorCores”: 3,

“executorMemory”: “20G”,

“numExecutors”: 50,

“queue”: “default”,

“name”: “test”,

“proxyUser”: “foo”,

“conf”: {“spark.jars.packages”: “xxx”},

“file”: “hdfs:///path/to/examples.jar”,

“args”: [1000],

}
```

- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/151164/how-to-submit-spark-application-through-livy-rest.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/quick-start-with-apache-livy

**--packages. All transitive dependencies will be handled when using this command.**

In Livy you need to go to interpreter settings page and add the new property under livy settings -

> livy.spark.jars.packages

And the value

```
com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1
```

Restart the interpreter and retry the query.

Comment: --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1   how do I specify this package part as given in the spark submit.

Comment: try                                                        
                 "spark.jars.packages":"com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1"

Comment: "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1"}, I getting  invalid json errors scala error, I couldn't paste the exact error as Iam away from work place.

Comment: Go to interpreter settings page and add the new property under livy settings - livy.spark.jars.packages and the value com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1 
  Restart the interpreter and retry the query.

Comment: curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/home/hadoop/test.py", "jars":"/usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC4.jar"}',  -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches
"Cannot deserialize instance of `scala.collection.immutable.List` out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 41] (through reference chain: org.apache.livy.server.batch.CreateBatchRequest[\"jars\"])"

Comment: curl -X POST --data '{"file": "s3:///pyscript/test01.py", "name": "LivyExample", "jars" : ["s3:///pytest/RedshiftJDBC4.jar"]}',  -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches

Comment: added the following setting in /etc/livy/conf.dist/livy.conf to the end of the file
  # livy.server.access-control.view-users
  livy.spark.jars.packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1
  
curl -X POST --data '{"file": "s3:///pyscript/test01.py", "queue": "my_queue", "name": "LivyExample", "jars" : ["s3:///pytest/RedshiftJDBC4.jar"]}',  -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed 2 finddata source: com.databricks.spark.redshift. Pls find pkges at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html how to restart interpreter?

Comment: ~]$ sudo initctl list | grep livy                                                                                                    livy-server start/pre-start, process 25812
[hadoop@ip-10- ~]$ sudo start  livy-server Not sure if this is the right way to restart the livy server...

Comment: curl -X POST --data '{"file": "s3://pyscript/test01.py", "name": "LivyExample", "jars" : ["s3://dev-iff-batch-explosion/pytest/RedshiftJDBC4.jar", "s3:///pytest/spark-redshift_2.10-3.0.0-preview1.jar"]}',  -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches, I added the second package as jar file, but now I am getting a  aws error,  You must specify a method for authenticating Redshift's connection to S3, but the script runs in spark-submit..

Comment: reading comments and logsinside comments  not easy ,plz update in your question what all you tried and getting error etc,seems like authentication error now your Livy is working

Comment: @vaquarkhan How to submit pyspark job to livy. The "file" field will it be the pyspark file? In the snippet above you include “file”: “hdfs:///path/to/examples.jar”. What should it be for pyspark?